Проблема с LaravelMPDF
Суть проблемы: не работает библиотека
Делаю все по инструкции из гита, но ошибка use PDF;, его будто нет. Создание нового экземпляра так же не помогает
Не ругается только если использую use Meneses\LaravelMpdf\LaravelMpdf;.
Так я могу создать новый экземпляр, но методы mPDF не работают тогда, искал много, но ответа не нашел. Попробовал создать новый чистый проект Laravel, там так же. Composer последней версии, Laravel 10, php 8.2.6.
Весь мой код:
namespace App\Http\Controllers\pdf;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Meneses\LaravelMpdf\LaravelMpdf;



// $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

class PdfController extends Controller
{
    //Функция получения страницы из PDF
    public function getPageFromPDF($pageNumber, $filePath){
        $mpdf = new LaravelMpdf();
        $mpdf->AddPage();
        $mpdf->SetTitle($sourceFile);
        $tplIdx = $mpdf->importPage($selectedPage);
        $mpdf->useTemplate($tplIdx);
        $mpdf->Output($outputFile, 'F');
    }
}

Так же ругается и в файле LaravelMpdf from vendor\carlos-meneses\laravel-mpdf\src\LaravelMpdf\LaravelMpdf.php
Ошибка в mPdf и Config
Надеюсь на помощь, заранее благодарю

как задать хороший вопрос

Ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384644/extension-gd-is-missing-from-your-system-laravel-composer-update
Все оказалось просто
Спасибо мне за ответ, который я искал в течении нескольких дней!)

Перенеси суть из ответа по ссылке в свой
